# Is it necessary to use nonstopmode in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, context-mkiv, options

Is it necessary to use --nonstopmode in ConTeXt  or using --once is enough ?

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do? It is not necessary to use either `--nonstepmode` or `--once`; you can compile a file by running `context filename`